# How to Prevent An App From Sleeping or Waking The App For Delivery of Message?

Tags: sleep, messaging, wakelock

We have been building a Whatsapp/Signal/Telegram type E2EE messaging/calling App. It already has over 150K + downloads on Android. However we request help of fellow members on the issue of delayed message on when App goes to background or deep sleep.

We have tried high priority FCM and APNS. Read past stackoverflow posts but we arent able to get the solution, other than whitelabeling the App. We have tried :- High Priority Push , Alarm Manager , Work Manager.

We have read

[Is posible use android push notifications in lan? without internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640040/is-posible-use-android-push-notifications-in-lan-without-internet/63443012#63443012)

[https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/425040/how-do-big-messaging-apps-keep-users-connected#:~:text=Primarily%2C%20they%20use%20the%20Apple,when%20the%20message%20is%20received](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/425040/how-do-big-messaging-apps-keep-users-connected#:%7E:text=Primarily%2C%20they%20use%20the%20Apple,when%20the%20message%20is%20received)

[Prevent my app to sleep when device goes to sleep mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41413965/prevent-my-app-to-sleep-when-device-goes-to-sleep-mode/76070936#76070936)

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock

Our App works fine when Apps are active. But suppose sending from Android to Android/IOS, if the recipient App is not in use for a few hours, the the message doesnt get delivered or call doesnt get connected. Once App is opened, messages start coming and missed call alerts too start coming.

We request Forum's help in knowing best practices for waking app in background (sleep/deep sleep) that we can follow.

For android 12 & 13 for some Chinese phones, we are unable to awake in case of deep sleep and doze mode.

Would greatly appreciate help from Forum. Just in case you would want to test the App, its Daakia and available on Appstore and Playstore.

Thanks
BSM